# Where to Store Large Photos to Access Them With my Website

Tags: web, storage

I want to develop a small website that shows all my personal photos as a gallery. My hosting provider limits me in storage. Let's say I have 20GB of photo data.

Where can I store my photos so I could access them all through API on any webpage of my website?

I thought of Google Cloud or similar but not yet reviewed the volume of work and cost involved. Any good recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: Might get some ideas if you posted this in a web forum. It's a very common hosting problem for any type of large files, not just photos.

Comment: And if the pictures are actually appropriately sized for web viewing, we're talking about something in the 80-100 kilophoto (or more) range. That's a *gallery*?

Comment: Great developers can organize terabytes of image data, can't they?

Comment: The big options here are Amazon S3 or Rackspace Cloud Files.

Comment: Can this be migrated to superuser or similar? We might be able to answer this but they would be best.

Answer (score 3):

SmugMug allows you to upload unlimited photos at high resolution and you can access them via API / oEmbed.

http://wiki.smugmug.net/display/API/Home

Even easier, you can just get a direct link to the resource and make it the 'href' of an HTML 'a'nchor tag.

http://help.smugmug.com/customer/portal/articles/93260-how-do-i-post-my-photos-in-forums-and-blogs

Answer (score 1):

I just recently started using Dropbox for my personal photos.  If you have less than 2.5g of images and you generate less than 20GB per day per link, you may be able to use Dropbox's free space.

I shy away from using it for hosting non-personal photos simply because I don't know if some companies would block dropbox.  I'd prefer that my professional site always load with photos.  :)